# Existence of one iterated integral but not the other

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I've been stuck on the following questions for quite a while now, there doesn't seem to be much material to read on double integrals of piecewise functions. 
If someone could please help me out.

Let Q = [0, 1] × [0, 1] and define f : Q → R by letting
f(x, y) = $\begin{cases}
           \frac{1}{q_x} &\text {if x,y $\in$ rationals}\\
           0, & \text {otherwise}
           \end{cases}$

We have for all y $\in$ [0,1] $\int_{0}^1 f(x,y)\,dx$ = 0
However, for x ∈ rationals ∩ [0, 1] the function f(x, y) is equal to $\frac{1}{q_x}$ for
rational y and is 0 otherwise. Thus the integral $\int_{0}^{1} f(x,y) dy $ does not exist. 
My question is can't we just switch x and y in the above paragraph and the same argument can be applied to the dx integral to show that it too doesn't exist.

Comment: It seems that you use $Q$ both for the unit square and for the set of rational numbers. – What is $q_x$? Is it the same as $qx$?

Comment: I believe that for any rational $x$, we define $p_x$ and $q_x$ such that $x = \dfrac{p_x}{q_x}$ and $\gcd(p_x,q_x) = 1$.

Comment: yes sorry its $q_x$ i've edited the question to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation so I will write my comment as an answer:

There is a mistake on your example. The integral $\int_0^1 f(x,y)dy$ exists because the set $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ (where $f(x,y)\neq 0$) have measure zero in $[0,1]$. Futhermore, $\int_0^1 f(x,y)dy=0$.

Comment: This is a good comment, but not an answer.